# Why do Python unicode strings require special treatment for UTF-8 BOM?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, io, character-encoding

For some reason, Python seems to be having issues with **BOM** when reading unicode strings from a **UTF-8** file. Consider the following:

```
with open('test.py') as f:
   for line in f:
      print unicode(line, 'utf-8')
```

Seems straightforward, doesn't it?

That's what I thought until I ran it from command line and got:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff'
>   in position 0: character maps to `<undefined>`

A brief visitation to Google revealed that BOM has to be **cleared manually**:

```
import codecs
with open('test.py') as f:
   for line in f:
      print unicode(line.replace(codecs.BOM_UTF8, ''), 'utf-8')
```

This one runs fine. However I'm struggling to see any merit in this.

**Is there a rationale behind above-described behavior?** In contrast, UTF-16 works seamlessly.

Comment: It cannot encode it because U+FEFF is an invalid noncharacter. It’s because UTF-8 files *aren’t supposed* to contain a BOM in them! They are neither required nor recommended. Endianness makes no sense with 8-bit code units. They screw things up, too, because you can no longer just do `cat a b c > abc` if those files have extraneous (read: *any*) BOMs in them. UTF-8  streams should not contain a BOM. If you need to specify the contents of the file, you are supposed to use a higher-level prototocl. This is just a Windows bug.

Comment: @tchrist - You know, this explanation in combination with Josh Lee's suggestion would make into a perfect answer.

Comment: Did your error message happen to mention the filename `cp437.py`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `'utf-8-sig'` encoding will consume the BOM signature on your behalf.

Comment: Yeah, that's the fix but I was more interested in the why.

Comment: @Gringo Suave: The funny thing is that the Unicode Standard does allow a BOM in UTF-8. See http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/ch02.pdf page 36, table 2-4.

Comment: Does anyone know if this still works if the BOM is not present?

Answer (score 12):

You wrote:

> ```
>  UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
> ```

When you specify the `"utf-8"` encoding in Python, it takes you at your word. UTF-8 files *aren’t supposed* to contain a BOM in them. They are neither required nor recommended. Endianness makes no sense with 8-bit code units.

**BOMs screw things up,** too, because you can no longer just do:

```
$ cat a b c > abc
```

if those UTF-8 files have extraneous (read: any) BOMs in them.  See now why BOMs are so stupid/bad/harmful in UTF-8? They actually break things.

A BOM is metadata, not data, and the UTF-8 encoding spec makes no allowance for them the way the UTF-16 and UTF-32 specs do. So Python took you at your word and followed the spec. Hard to blame it for that.

If you are trying to use the BOM as a filetype magic number to specify the contents of the file, you really should not be doing that. You are really supposed to use a higher-level prototocl for these metadata purposes, just as you would with a MIME type.

This is just another lame Windows bug, the workaround for which is to use the alternate encoding `"utf-8-sig"` to pass off to Python.

Comment: You can encode U+FEFF into UTF-8 if you like. You can’t encode it into latin-1, which is what 'charmap' uses for me.

Comment: @Josh: You’re right. I keep getting dylexic malfunction and reading FEFF as FFFE. It’s FFFE that’s illegal for open interchange. FEFF is just `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`.

Comment: It is very frustrating to deal with these, and I'd love to call this a Windows bug, but the standard does indeed allow BOMs in UTF-8 files.  See http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/ch02.pdf page 36, table 2-4 and the text "_[a BOM] may 
be encountered in contexts where UTF-8 data is converted from other encoding forms that 
use a BOM or where the BOM is used as a UTF-8 signature._" and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark and [Re: pre-HTML5 and the BOM from Asmus Freytag on 2012-07-13 (Unicode Mail List Archive)](http://www.unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2012-m07/0268.html)